# sql pivot summarize table and compare rows

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql, pivot

I have this three table
with many-to-many relation between account and bounse , i want to compare the bounse for each account with the previous month by subtract current month's bounse with the previous month

tbl_account

```
account_id  account_name
----------- ---------------------
1        Account1
2        Account2
```

tbl_bounse

```
bounse_id   bounse_name
----------- -------------
42          bounseA
43          bounseB
44          BounseC
```

tbl_detail ( the link table between tbl_account and tbl_bounse )

```
detail_accound_id detail_bounce_id detail_value         detail_id   detail_date
----------------- ---------------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
1              42               24000                158981      2013-05-05
1              42               25000                159113      2013-06-06
1              43               150                  158982      2013-05-05
1              43               150                  159114      2013-06-06
1              44               23000                158983      2013-05-05
1              44               25150                159115      2013-06-06
2              42               20000                159025      2013-05-05
2              42               23000                159157      2013-06-06
2              43               400                  159026      2013-05-05
2              43               350                  159158      2013-06-06
2              44               10000                159021      2013-05-05
2              44               11000                159159      2013-06-06
```

and I want to summarize the result as

```
accound_id      detail_date     BounseA      BounseB      BounseC 
-----------     -----------     -------      -------      -------     
1           2013-05-05      24000        150      23000
1           2013-06-06      25000        150      25500
1           differ date     1000         0        2500
2           2013-05-05      20000        400      10000
2           2013-06-06      23000        350      11000
2           differ date     3000         -50      1000
```

returned Temp Table as

```
accound_id      detail_date     BounseA      BounseB      BounseC 
-----------     -----------     -------      -------      -------     
1           differ date     1000         0        2500
2           differ date     3000         -50      1000
```

i'm trying to use pivot and dynamic sql but i don't know how to subtract the rows and insert the result of subtracting into temp table

SQL server 2008 r2 , the query using T-SQL or LINQ

Comment: please confirm whether you have only two date, as you want to get the difference between two dates only.

Comment: +1 for good explanation ..

Comment: YES I have ONLY TWO DATE to compare ( current Month and previous Month) , but i have many date detail stored in tbl_detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a CTE to do the pivots and then use either a windowed function to get the most current date dynamically or add a variable to potentially do comparisons of past month.  Example is self extracting with table variables so if you have SQL Management Studio 2008 or higher it will run as is:

```
declare @account table ( id int identity, name varchar(16) );
declare @bonus table ( id int identity(42,1), bonusname varchar(16) );
declare @detail table ( accountId int, bonusid int, detailvalue int, detailid int, detaildate date);

insert into @account values ( 'Account1'),('Account2');
insert into @bonus values ('bonusA'),('bonusB'),('BonusC');
insert into @detail values ( 1, 42, 24000, 158981, '2013-05-05')
,(1, 42, 25000, 159113      ,'2013-06-06')
,(1, 43, 150, 158982        ,'2013-05-05')
,(1, 43, 150, 159114        ,'2013-06-06')
,(1, 44, 23000, 158983      ,'2013-05-05')
,(1, 44, 25150, 159115      ,'2013-06-06')
,(2, 42, 20000, 159025      ,'2013-05-05')
,(2, 42, 23000, 159157      ,'2013-06-06')
,(2, 43, 400, 159026        ,'2013-05-05')
,(2, 43, 350, 159158        ,'2013-06-06')
,(2, 44, 10000, 159021      ,'2013-05-05')
,(2, 44, 11000, 159159      ,'2013-06-06')
;

-- Method 1 determines the current month and year by finding greatest date in your table, there is an issue with this method if you want to see other months.
with cte as 
    (
    select
        a.id
    ,   d.detaildate
    -- perform pivots based on id
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusA' then detailvalue end) as BonusA
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusB' then detailvalue end) as BonusB
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusC' then detailvalue end) as BonusC
    -- find the maximum date with a windowed function changing scope to group by (partition by) the identifier of the account
    ,   max( d.detaildate) over(partition by a.id) as MaxDate
    from @account a
        join @detail d on a.id = d.accountId
        join @bonus b on d.bonusid = b.id
    group by 
        a.id
    ,   d.detaildate
    )
select 
    id
,   max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusA end)  -
    max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusA end)  as BonusADif
,   max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusB end)  -
    max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusB end) as BonusBDif
,   max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusC end) -
    max(case when Year(MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusC end) as BonusCDif
from cte
group by id
;

-- Method 2 determines the current month and year by YOU listing a variable, this offers more flexibility in the future.  
-- You could create a function or proc off of this for even more functionality

declare @MaxDate date = '6-1-2013';

with cte as 
    (
    select
        a.id
    ,   d.detaildate
    -- perform pivots based on id
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusA' then detailvalue end) as BonusA
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusB' then detailvalue end) as BonusB
    ,   max(case when b.bonusname = 'BonusC' then detailvalue end) as BonusC
    -- find the maximum date with a windowed function changing scope to group by (partition by) the identifier of the account
    from @account a
        join @detail d on a.id = d.accountId
        join @bonus b on d.bonusid = b.id
    group by 
        a.id
    ,   d.detaildate
    )
select 
    id
,   max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusA end)  -
    max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusA end)  as BonusADif
,   max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusB end)  -
    max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusB end) as BonusBDif
,   max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) = Month(detailDate) then BonusC end) -
    max(case when Year(@MaxDate) = Year(detaildate) and Month(@MaxDate) - 1 = Month(detailDate) then BonusC end) as BonusCDif
from cte
group by id
```

Comment: thank you for answer ,with the second method ...  the 'bounse's is a table (bounseA, bounseB....... BounseN) , and i need to convert bounse names  it to columns dynamically on the result

Comment: You would to do dynamic sql like: 1. Find distinct bonuses select distinct bonusname from bonustable 2. Put them in a cte to then reference 3. insert them into another table but alter their statements to be 'max(case when b.bonusname = ''' + temp.name + ''' then detailvalue end) as ' + b.bonusname.  4. Create a temp table and insert the first part of the select 'select a.id, d.detaile' 5. Do a while loop where you do a count of the rows in the temp table step 3 and insert NEW rows into the table in step 4.  5. Now insert the from expression and do a dynamic insert for the group by.